# Python requests.post fails in 421

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, httpretty

I have the following code in the implementation ([uses requests lib](https://pypi.org/project/requests)):

```
def call_service(product_ids: Set[str])
   response = requests.post(
      json={"product_ids": product_ids},
      url="http://whatever.com",
   )

   if response.status_code == 421:
      raise MisRedirectedRequest()
```

I'm using [HTTPretty's](https://httpretty.readthedocs.io) to simulate this in a test:

```
@httpretty.activate
def test_http_status_code_421():
    httpretty.register_uri(
        method=httpretty.POST,
        uri="http://whatever.com",
        body="{}",
        status=421,
    )

   with pytest.raises(MisRedirectedRequest):
      call_service({"123", "543"})
```

However, `MisRedirectedRequest` is never raised. The test doesn't pass.
By debugging, I get this in the implementation:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

The weird thing is that I tried with other HTTP error codes and it works fine (e.g. `420`, `500`).

Comment: Your body (and http headers) aren't the same between both code blocks

Comment: but the body above (impl. code) is the *request* post body; the body below (test code) is the stubbed *response* body.. so it's normal they don't match.

Comment: (and it works if I swap from 421 to 420 in both places)

Comment: Okay, well, we don't know what your server is supposed to return, so keeping the actual HTTP request the same would make sense. Looks like you are actually making a request, not mocking one. Specifically, `call_service` would need to accept the URI argument from `httpretty.register_uri`, I believe, and not set its own (which could easily be different)

Comment: But since Python allows monkey patching, HTTPretty's can match whatever URL - capturing that call as well. In real life that would be another URL but it would still be the same in tests and implementation. I've done that in everywhere so far and it works. Except here.

Comment: It works similarly to Java's WireMock. In both, the implementation thinks it's doing a real call. In Python you don't even need to inject a fake/localhost URL due to the monkey patching being more clever.

Comment: httpretty.register_uri prepares a mock. Then it's supposed to be matched and consumed.

Comment: Interesting. So, what happens when you remove `body="{}"`?

Comment: HTTPretty's puts in some dummy default, which is irrelevant here because it's not being used in the implementation code. Only the status code is being used in that if.

Comment: it was a limitation in HTTPretty's: https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/pull/458

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247895/discussion-between-luis-soares-and-onecricketeer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I discovered that HTTPretty did not support 421.
I created a [PR](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty/pull/458) but meanwhile, this is the workaround:

```
from httpretty.http import STATUSES

STATUSES[421] = "Misdirected Request"
```

Update: PR is merged.